# Fisher Exact Test: using cumulative or mass probability?

Tags: fishers-exact-test

I want to compare data between two series of terms.
My first one is the whole thesaurus of terms that contains 270 terms, 123 of which are "nouns".
The second one is a selection depending on various criteria, thus X terms, x of which are nouns.

Fisher's Exact Test will compare x/X with 123/270, roughtly, with function shown here;
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test

My problem is I don't know if my test is one-tailed or two-tailed,
and if I have to use cumulative/density probability or mass probability?
My guess would be density probability as usually that's what used to test hypotheses,
but I confess my stats fundamentals are both far and never have been quite good to my great despair.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As described in detail elsewhere on this site, Fisher's "exact" test is not very accurate due to conservatism.  So why is it worth the trouble to you?

Comment: Well, this is standard procedure for enrichment test, I don't decide about the usual practices of my science field.
There are other methods but I was required to use this one too. Also, I think anyway, It would be good to understand these concepts better so I would use them better in all stats, regardless of what's the test employed.

Comment: That is unfortunate.

Comment: Yeah. Still, I still want to  understand.